# Cordova FileTransfer Download error

Tags: android, cordova, download, file-transfer, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a simple hybrid app which should download files with cordova 2.3.0. From the documentation:

```
var filePath = someFullPath; //e.g. "file:///mnt/sdcard/myfile.pdf"
var uri = encodeURI("http://someurl.com/myfile.pdf");

var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.download(
            uri,
            filePath,
            function(entry) {
                console.error("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
            },
            function(error) {
                console.error("download error source " + error.source);
                console.error("download error target " + error.target);
                console.error("donwload error code " + error.code);
                console.error("http: "+error.http_status);

            }
    );
}
```

The outcome is error 3, Connection_Err, with http_status 401, the resource myfile.pdf is public on a http server with no auth required.

I have tried both creating the file file://mnt/sdcard/myfile.pdf with getFile("my file.pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail); or just setting a string to an existing directory. It didn't work in both scenarios.

Can you please advise? I have to use cordova 2.3.0.

**UPDATE:**

I think my problem is very close to this one: [FileTransfer in Phonegap code 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625710/filetransfer-in-phonegap-code-401)

I have Android API 17, cordova 2.3.0, I need to set allow origin = "*", but I can't create the config.xml file, for some reasons it throws errors. Have you faced this problem?

I created the folder xml inside res (there wasn't one) and created a file config.xml inside such folder. The content of the config.xml is

```
 <access origin="*"></access>
```

when I run the application I get an alert with this error: Error Initializing Cordova: Class not found

Comment: if you download phonegap 2.3.0 as a zip file. In that zip file you find /phonegap-2.3.0/lib/android/xml folder just copy that xml into your eclipse res folder. Thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the code was correct, it was a problem with my configuration of the framework:

this project had another project as library dependence. This project didn't have a config.xml file where to whitelist URLs. The library project had! I just needed to add the

```
<access origin="http://*.somedomain.com"></access>
```

to the "right" config.xml cordova file, which was in a Library project, not in the main project itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my setup, having access was not sufficient.
I added plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist to my app.
Then it worked fine.